# mod_rewrite help needed for 410 status code

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, http-status-code-410

I want to send 410 status code if there is any `?` on the URL. Because the site is only works with SEO enabled URLs (Like `www.domain.com/seo-enabled-urls`).

With the StatckOverflow community support did this 301 redirection that works perfectly:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^romance-package-two\.html$ http://www.domain.com/wedding-champagne [QSA,NC,R=301,L]
```

In the same way I want to add 410 message code that will tell Google (like search engines) permanently deleted so we wont have problem with SEO unknown or not found URLs.

If the URL looks like this

```
www.domain.com/seo-enabled-urls?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

I want to keep the same URL but just with that 410 code like this

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} ^(.*&)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^1$  same url code [QSA,NC,R=410,L]
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't redirect with a HTTP 410 code -- 410 means that the requested page is permanently gone, and that there's no replacement:

> **410 Gone**
>
> The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no forwarding address is known. This condition is expected to be considered permanent. Clients with link editing capabilities SHOULD delete references to the Request-URI after user approval. If the server does not know, or has no facility to determine, whether or not the condition is permanent, the status code 404 (Not Found) SHOULD be used instead. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.

-- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.11

---

The corresponding definition for HTTP 301 indicates that it's already exactly what you wanted:

> **301 Moved Permanently**
>
> The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned URIs. Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically re-link references to the Request-URI to one or more of the new references returned by the server, where possible. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.

-- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2

Comment: Hi those(var=val&var2=val) parameters doesn't affect page results anymore. It was wrong URL parameters and i want to remove it from google bot indexing.

Comment: So send a 301 redirect from the original URL to the URL without parameters -- like what you're proposing in the question, but with `R=301` instead of `R=410`.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is no longer correct at least as far back as Apache 2.0, where mod_rewrite supports a 410 GONE target:

> 'gone|G' (force URL to be gone)
> This forces the current URL to be gone - it immediately sends back a HTTP response of 410 (GONE). Use this flag to mark pages which no longer exist as gone.

(see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

That means that a rule such as you had above should simply be:

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} ^(.*&)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^1$ - [G]
```

Comment: The example is incorrect - you must include "-", e.g.:

`RewriteRule ^1$ - [G]`